# How to obtain session ID after remember me login in Symfony2?

Tags: php, session, symfony, redis

I'm using "remember me" autologin in Symfony 2.3, pretty standard configuration:

```
security:
    firewalls:
    secured_auth:
        (...)
        remember_me:
            key: RememberMeKey
            lifetime: 5184000
            path: /
            domain: ~
```

I'm using Redis session handler (native PHP Redis session module).

It works as expected, no problem here. After entering the website for the first time after a long time, user is logged in automatically.

The problem is that I need to use session id in my controller (actually it's passed to the view, where it's used as an auth key for external services accessed by AJAX). To get session ID inside a controller I use `$this->get('session')->getId()` and normally it works just fine, except for when the user enters site for the first time and he's autologged using remember me token. For this one request, session ID returned by `$this->get('session')->getId()` (or `session_id()`) in the controller is an empty string. After reloading the page everything works as it's supposed to again.

The only idea that comes to mind right now is not using session id in a controller at all, instead getting it from cookie in JavaScript client side, but that's not a very good solution. How do I get session ID inside controller after automatically logging in? I hope I'm making myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question for future generations...

It's an issue with Symfony:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9255

The dirty workaround is to manually start the session on autologin in authentication handler

```
public function onAuthenticationInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $e) {
    $token = $e->getAuthenticationToken();
    $request = $e->getRequest();

    if($token instanceof Token\RememberMeToken) {
        $url = $request->getRequestUri();

        $this->session->start();
        $this->userProvider->refreshUser($token->getUser());
    }
}
```